# How to add YouTube light theme parameter

Tags: php, video, parameters, youtube, embed

My website has a dark theme and so whenever I embed a video it uses the default dark theme. I'm wondering how I can add the parameter: `"theme=light"` using PHP. I was considering using CSS to override the actual iframe styles but I'm thinking using PHP action would be better. Can anyone help me out as I'm not very familiar with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

At place you want to write that "theme = lite" add:

```
<?php echo 'theme = light'; ?>
```

But it doesn't make much sense writing out static content with PHP ?! Why you want to write it with PHP when you can just leave static value of it?

Comment: Lol I'm sorry I don't really understand what you mean by leaving the static value.

Comment: theme=light is a constant...it's always the same...So there is no need to involve the PHP if you are not going to change it conditionally.